# Apply 9-patch drawable to Button, keeping default padding

Tags: java, android, layout, button, drawable

I'm attempting to customise the look of a Button using a 9-patch drawable with no padding defined within in (no pixels on the right or bottom inside the 9-patch editor).

Is there a simple way to apply a 9-patch drawable to a button and maintain the button's default size. For example, when I apply the 9-patch to the Easy button shown below, it is a different size to the other default styled buttons, which share the same layout, except for the 9-patch style.


Mdpi layout:

[image: mdpi layout]

Hdpi layout:

[image]

So basically, is there a way to make the Easy button the same size as Medium and Hard, on both mdpi and hdpi screens, without making a new 9-patch for each density, and working out the correct padding.

Thanks in advance for your help, I can provide more information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some more research it seems that it isn't easily possible to use one 9-patch drawable for all screen densities.

The link below states you need different drawables for each density:

[Custom Color Buttons for Android](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/custom-color-buttons-for-android/)

> 3.1. Create images 9-patch images for the different colors that you need and put them into drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi (yes, you will need two versions if you want your buttons to look good on different devices).

If anyone knows any different though, your help would be much appreciated.